# How to find task_struct for a given sock in a kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Does anybody happen to know how I can (efficiently) get a struct task_struct for a given struct sock in a kernel module (i.e. the process that created a given network layer socket) ?

I apologise if I am missing the obvious, it may be due to the fact that I am rather new to kernel development. But I've been trying to find that link for days now. My biggest hope was to use sk->sk_socket->file->f_owner.pid. I could then have used f_getown() to get the pid and from there.
But somehow this idea didn't work out, at least for an AF_INET type socket. From looking at the kernel code in __sock_socket() and called functions, it seemes the f_owner member is never pointed to current.

So I thought file->f_owner maybe shouldn't be used any more, but I didn't find any such information. Actually, during my search, I found that sock_ioctl() is using f_setown() and f_getown(). So file->f_owner doesn't seem to be obsolete. Which leads to my second question: If file->f_owner is not obsolete, why wouldn't it be set during socket creation ?

Since then, I have only been hitting dead ends. Any hint in the right direction would be much appreciated. - Many thanks.

Comment: Field `file->f_owner` is of type `struct fown_struct` which is about `F_SETOWN` fcntl code. It is not about a creator(opener) of the file, it is about SIGIO signal receiver. See [man fcntl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) for more info.

Comment: "how I can (efficiently) get a struct task_struct for a given struct sock in a kernel module (i.e. the process that created a given network layer socket) ?" - Do you mean the process which creates the socket via `socket` call? I don't think the kernel stores this information, since that process could die at any moment (but the socket could exist because of `fork` or `pthread_create`)

Comment: My ultimate goal would be a kind of lookup that gives you the process(es) that hold(s) a specific socket.